# Apache redirect on one line

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-redirect

How do I perform a redirect with RewriteRule on one line.

For example I'd like to combine the following:

```
RewriteRule ^sport\/baseball http://www.espn.com [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^sport\/football http://www.espn.com [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^sport\/(base|foot)ball http://www.espn.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: He needs a modified rule like `^sport\/((base|foot)ball|soccer) http://www.espn.com [L,R=301]`, but you know that right? Also if you removed your comment, I think the point is that the rule(s) should be short.

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
RewriteRule ^sport\/(baseball|football) http://www.espn.com [L,R=301]
```